# Excel VBA - I need to paste a range of data down to the end the data of rows.

Tags: excel, vba

ie:  I have data in E2:W2 and I'd like to paste it to E:W depending on how many rows there are in column A.  Each time I run the macro it will be a different number of lines.  It could be 3 or 2000 rows

Also, could be 1, so no copying necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will copy E2:W2 all the way down until there are no filled cells in column A

```
Sub CopyEW

if cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row>2 then _
    range("E2:W2").copy range("E2:W2").resize(cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row)

end if

end sub
```